# MACD line with signal line is way above 0 line where histogram lies

Tags: python, stock

I have encountered strange thing while calculating MACD of silver.
This is what I am getting:

[image: My MACD chart]

I am calculating it using EMA like this:

```
MACD line = EMA(price array, n1) - EMA(price array, n2)
MACD signal = EMA(MACD line, n3)
Histogram = MACD line - MACD Signal
```

```
def EMA(close_price_arr, n):
    a = 2/(n + 1)
    EMA_n = np.empty((1, len(close_price_arr)))

    for i in range(len(close_price_arr)):

        if i < n - 1:
            # creating NaN values where it is impossible to calculate EMA to drop the later
            EMA_n[0, i] = 'NaN'
        if i >= n - 1:
            # Calaculating nominator and denominator of EMA
            for j in range(n):
                nominator_ema += close_price_arr[i - j] * (1-a)**(j)
                denominator_ema += (1 - a)**(j)



            nominator_ema += close_price_arr[i - j] * (1-a)**(j)
            denominator_ema += (1 - a)**n
            EMA_n[0, i] = nominator_ema / denominator_ema
        nominator_ema = 0
        denominator_ema = 0
    return EMA_n

def MACD(price_arr, n1, n2, n3):
    EMA_n1 = EMA(close_price_arr=price_arr, n=n1)
    EMA_n2 = EMA(close_price_arr=price_arr, n=n2)
    MACD_unor = EMA_n1 - EMA_n2
    x, y = MACD_unor.shape
    MACD_unor_trans = np.reshape(MACD_unor,y)
    Signal_line_EMA_n3 = EMA(close_price_arr=MACD_unor_trans, n=n3)
    histogram = MACD_unor - Signal_line_EMA_n3


    return MACD_unor, Signal_line_EMA_n3, histogram

# Specyfying root folder, file folder and file
FILE = 'TVC_SILVER, 5.csv'
FOLDER = 'src'
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = '.'
csv_path = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, FOLDER, FILE)

# reading csv
price_data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, delimiter=',')

price_data_copy = price_data.copy()

price_data_nodate = price_data.copy().drop('time', axis=1)

price_data_np = price_data_nodate.to_numpy(dtype='float32')

close_price = price_data_np[:, 3]

MACD_main, MACD_signal, histogram = MACD(price_arr=close_price, n1=12, n2=26, n3=9)

plt.plot(MACD_main[0, :], label='MACD main 12,26')
plt.plot(MACD_signal[0, :], label='MACD signal 9')
x_bar, y_bar = histogram.shape
ypos = np.arange(y_bar)
plt.bar(ypos, histogram[0, :], label='MACD histogram')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong so that I get wrong chart.
If you'd give me an advise on what I am doing wrong I'd be grateful :)

[Here you can download my .csv to see it yourself, It is from transfernow.com so you shouldn't be worried](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/202207270ajSQAW6)

Comment: After resolving various imports, when I try to run your example, I get errors. Neither `MACDline_trans` nor `MACD_unor` is defined, maybe more.

Comment: My bad, I have edited it out, before I posted it I have changed the names so they would be more understandable for english speakers.
You can try it out rn.